# Correct way to extract months and write a case when statement

Tags: oracle

I have written this case when statement but I am getting an error, if someone could please help fix my code, I would appreciate that:

```
CASE 
    WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM APPROVED_DATE) AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM END_DATE) BETWEEN 1 AND 3 THEN APPROVED_DATE
    WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM APPROVED_DATE) AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM END_DATE) BETWEEN 4 AND 6 THEN APPROVED_DATE
    WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM APPROVED_DATE) AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM END_DATE) BETWEEN 7 AND 9 THEN APPROVED_DATE
    WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM APPROVED_DATE) AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM END_DATE) BETWEEN 10 AND 12 THEN APPROVED_DATE
    ELSE END_DATE
END pitem_date
```

this is the error I get:
**SQL Error [920] [42000]: ORA-00920: invalid relational operator**

thank you

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: an English (not code) explanation of the logic you are trying to implement because your code does not have value syntax so it is unclear what you are trying to achieve. Also, it would help to include the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for your sample data and the expected output for that sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not work because:

```sql
WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM APPROVED_DATE)
AND  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM END_DATE) BETWEEN 1 AND 3
```

Is invalid because you are not comparing the value from the first `EXTRACT` to anything.

---

If you are trying to check if `APPROVED_DATE` and `END_DATE` are within the same quarter (independent of year) then:

```
CASE 
WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM APPROVED_DATE) BETWEEN 1 AND 3
AND  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM END_DATE)      BETWEEN 1 AND 3
THEN APPROVED_DATE
WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM APPROVED_DATE) BETWEEN 4 AND 6
AND  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM END_DATE)      BETWEEN 4 AND 6
THEN APPROVED_DATE
WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM APPROVED_DATE) BETWEEN 7 AND 9
AND  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM END_DATE)      BETWEEN 7 AND 9
THEN APPROVED_DATE
WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM APPROVED_DATE) BETWEEN 10 AND 12
AND  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM END_DATE)      BETWEEN 10 AND 12
THEN APPROVED_DATE
ELSE END_DATE
END AS pitem_date
```

If you want to check if the dates are in the same quarter, including year, then:

```
CASE 
WHEN TRUNC(APPROVED_DATE, 'Q') = TRUNC(END_DATE, 'Q')
THEN APPROVED_DATE
ELSE END_DATE
END AS pitem_date
```